# Trying to create a nested class' show - getting the error 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StocksController#show Could not find table 'time_deltas''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, show, nested-class

I'm trying to follow along the Rails getting started guide except for the fact that I'm using Stocks instead of articles and TimeDeltas instead of comments. Now when I go to the view I keep getting this error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StocksController#show Could not find
>   table 'time_deltas'
>
> on line:      @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build

Heres my view:

```
<h1> Stock </h1>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Hashtag</th>        
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= @stock.name %></td>
            <td><%= @stock.hashtag %></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<h2>Deltas: </h2>
  <table> 
    <tr>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Hashtag</th>    
    </tr>
  <% @stock.deltas.each do |delta| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @delta.start %></td>
      <td><%= @delta.length %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<h2>Add a TimeDelta:</h2>
<%= form_for([@stock, @stock.time_deltas.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :length %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :length %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', stocks_path%>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stock_path(@stock)%>
```

Heres my stocks controller:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @stock = Stock.new
    end

    def index
        @stocks = Stock.all
    end

    def create
        # XXX Add columns for delta and current standing when we get there
        # they can intiate to nil
        @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)
        if @stock.save
            redirect_to @stock  
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @stock = find_stock
        @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build
    end

    def edit
        @stock = find_stock
    end

    def update
        @stock = find_stock


        if @stock.update(stock_params)
            redirect_to @stock
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @stock = find_stock
        @stock.destroy

        redirect_to stocks_path
    end

    private 
        def stock_params
            params.require(:stock).permit(:name, :hashtag)
        end

        def find_stock
      return Stock.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Heres my TimeDelta controller

```
class TimeDeltasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build
    # respond_with(@stock, @time_delta)
  end
  def create
    @stock = Stock.find(time_delta_params)
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.create(params[:stock])
    redirect_to stock_path(@stock)
  end

  private 
    def time_delta_params
      params.require(:time_delta).permit(:start, :length)
    end
end
```

I've tried re running my migrations as well and to no-avail, any suggestions?

EDIT: Both models
Stock:

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deltas
    has_many :time_deltas
    validates :hashtag, :name , presence: true, :uniqueness => true, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

Time Delta:

```
class TimeDelta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock
end
```

Database Schema:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140412204548) do

  create_table "delta", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "start"
    t.integer  "length"
    t.integer  "stock_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "delta", ["stock_id"], name: "index_delta_on_stock_id"

  create_table "queries", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "tweet"
    t.integer  "tweetId"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "stocks", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "name"
    t.text     "hashtag"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "time_delta", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "start"
    t.integer  "length"
    t.integer  "stock_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "time_delta", ["stock_id"], name: "index_time_delta_on_stock_id"

end
```

Comment: Show your model please..

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea added both!

Comment: Do you have a table called time_deltas?

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea i tried select * from time_deltas in sqlite and got nothing.. shouldnt the table or at least a igration for it of been created when the model was created ?

Comment: How did you create this model?

Comment: @Oscarrails generate model TimeDelta start:datetime length:integer stock:references

Comment: Then I ran a rake db:migrate

Comment: Im not fond of creating models/tables/etc through migrate so this is kind of beyond my scope. But, can you check which database your app is running with? (config/database) and then check if the table time_deltas is present on that database?

Comment: db/development.sqlite3 how do I check if the table is present?

Comment: This will be my last comment since we're supposed to avoid extended discussions in the comments.. But depending on the database engine you are using, you should be able to check the databases present in your server. You'd either do it via command line OR using an database management application. Check this for further reference http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#setup-the-database

Comment: I used to check sqlite database by using this addon for firefox. Maybe it will be a help. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea included my DB schema, its in there, any other ideas what might be causing this ?

Comment: You are calling table time_deltas and your table name is time_delta.

Comment: It should be @stock.time_delta.build OR rename your table to time_deltas in your Dabatase.

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea This changes the error to 'undefined method `time_delta' for #<Stock:0x007fdaf7391528>' for the line '@time_delta = @stock.time_delta.build' in the Stocks#show.

Comment: Because you should have has_many :time_delta (not time_deltas) in your stock model. I think it'd have been better to rename the table to a plural form since it'd be more convenient.

Comment: OscarValdezEsquea I just did it for convience Ill fix it correctly later once I have everything working, Now I'm getting this error 'uninitialized constant Stock::TimeDeltum' at the same line in Stocks#show '@time_delta = @stock.time_delta.build'

Comment: That's why i'd suggest you rename the table to a plural form, i had ran into this issue in the past with a model whose table had a name in singular form. It did the same putting (um) at the end of the called model (in my case i had Familia and it turned it into Familium). I fixed it adding some inflections. Try adding: 
   inflect.irregular 'time_delta', 'time_deltas' to inflections (config/initializers/inflections.rb).. But i strongly suggest you rename the table to a plural form.

Comment: It probably has somthing to do with the pluraization.. but I've already added an inflection 'ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect| 
 inflect.irregular 'time_delta', 'time_deltas'
end

Comment: Okay ill try renaming the table to the plural form

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea that totally worked!! Thank you so much !!! Can you give me an answer so that I can approve it ?

Comment: Sure, i will work on that ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created your table via migration the name of your "time_deltas" table was actually created as "time_delta". Keeping the database name in singular form could bring up troubles in the future. The best suggestion is to rename your database to "time_deltas" and it'd work just fine. Also, i noticed that there's another table with a singular name form (delta). I suggest you rename it to "deltas".

Happy coding!